# Partial view gives ambiguous reference error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco

I'm trying to use a partial view to render the meta data and the header image (separate partial view) into the _layout.cshtml. While doeing this i get the following error: CS0104: 'Meta' is an ambiguous reference between 'Namespace.Models.Meta' and 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Meta'

I tried changing the name of Meta to evreything else, even non meaning keyboard spins like dfguyfgfjhagjhsgf. Still not working.

The meta.cs clase looks as follow:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web;

namespace Namespace.Models
{
    public class Meta
    {
        public Meta(IPublishedContent content)
        {
            Name = content.Name;

            Description = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("metaDescription");
            Photo = content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("metaHeaderImage");
        }

        public IPublishedContent Photo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The Meta.cshtml looks as follow:

```
@model Meta
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>@Model.Name</title>
<meta name="description" content="@Model.Description">

<meta property="og:title" content="@Model.Name" />
<meta property="og:image" content="@Model.Photo" />
```

The call for the partial view in the _layout.cshtml is:

`@Html.Partial("Meta", Model.Meta)`

I would like to know what the error means and a possible solution would be great.

PS. I have done a project in the past with the same setup for partial views as this time. back then it worked just fine. No, i have no longer acces to this older project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambiguous reference error comes when there are two classes with same name in your solution and the code cannot decide which one to use. In your case the class `Meta` is present in `Namespace.Model` and also `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels`. You can change the **Meta.cshtml** file to refer the correct `Meta` class by using fully qualified class name like so.

```
@model Namespace.Model.Meta
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it would be somthing small. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help. Sometimes the smallest thing takes the longest time to debug!